# Непонятный конфликт скриптов

Tags: javascript

тут такое дело что на странице есть несколько слайдеров. после каждого слайдера идет js код с параметрами настройки данного слайдера. проблема в том что все слаййдеры одинаковы и код у них получается одинаковый (+- какая то опция) но есть два слайдера с точно таким же кодом как и устальных но когда они есть на странице то из за них перестают работать другие js скрипты
пример кода из за которого не работают остальные скрипты

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$("#touchcarousel-21").touchCarousel({"snapToItems":true,"pagingNavControls":false,"itemsPerMove":5,"loopItems":false,"directionNav":true,"directionNavAutoHide":false,"autoplay":true,"autoplayDelay":3000,"autoplayStopAtAction":true,"keyboardNav":false,"dragUsingMouse":true,"transitionSpeed":400,"itemFallbackWidth":300,"scrollbar":false,"scrollbarAutoHide":true,"scrollbarTheme":"dark"});});
</script>
```

вот [пример страницы](http://adminwp.ru/111.html) (там слайдеры скрыты, так что посмотрите исходный код)
проблема именно в двух последних слайдерах, если их поставить первыми то все последующие просто перестанут работать.
что именно в эти двух слайдерах что они блочат другие хотя в них такой же код как и в остальных???

Comment: сделайте fiddle, пример страницы не годится, так вы почините и никто никогда не узнает в чем была проблема.

**помните - этот сайт сделан не для того чтобы помочь лично вам, а ещё и  для тех кто наступит на те-же грабли**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. дело было в том что слайдер листался по пять штук, а в категории было меньше 5((